# Javascript cost calculator wont work as supposed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

Hello I am new to Js and I want to make a cost calculation function. So far it works but Its not what I want to have. Here is how it looks

```
<script>
                    function finalCost(){
                    var roomType = document.getElementById("roomtype").value;
                    var roomNum = document.getElementById("rooms").value;
                    var personNum = document.getElementById("atoma").value;
                    var childNum = document.getElementById("paidia").value;
                    var resFacilities = 
                    document.getElementById("meal").value;
                    var atoma = childNum + personNum;
                    var roomty = (parseInt(roomType));                                              

                    var total = +roomty + +atoma + +((resFacilities));


                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total;
                    }
                    </script>
```

However, I want to have something like that: ( It wont work I know)

```
<script>
                    function finalCost(){
                    var roomType = document.getElementById("roomtype").value;
                    var roomNum = document.getElementById("rooms").value;
                    var personNum = document.getElementById("atoma").value;
                    var childNum = document.getElementById("paidia").value;
                    var resFacilities = 
                    document.getElementById("meal").value;
                    var atoma = childNum + personNum;
                    var roomty = (parseInt(roomType));


                    var total = +roomty*roomNum  + +atoma + +((resFacilities)*atoma);


                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total;
                    }
                    </script>
```

If I enter the above code the cost wont work at all If i enter it without the *roomNum the cost will work without the meal included.

Please give me some advice as I am really frustrated by this issue.

Comment: can you put your code on CodePen?

Comment: @admin asking to include all of their code and HTML is ok, but asking to put it on a specific site seems strange

Comment: O sir my sir @Slai. I don't remember other site name. Don't put question on each and every thing. Panos1221, Slai is angry please put it on some other site other than codepen

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly because I'm unsure of the exact calculation you are trying to compute:

```
    // Total calculated as room type times number of rooms times number of people. 
    // Adding meal costs per person.
    var total = roomty*roomNum*atoma +(resFacilities*atoma);
```

Comment: Its a hotel booking form. atoma means people in my language forgot to change sorry. I have values on the form and the meal is 30 per person so I want to multiply atoma with meal EDIT: doesnt work :(

Comment: I do that as the second half of the above. I'm more unsure of the roomtype, people and rooms relationship you are going for.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine please see console output [image: here]

Of this is not what you looking for. Put your html, javascript somewhere at one place. Where you code can be executed.

Comment: Its not as I have not these values. For example here is the code for one kid '<option value="20">1</option>' each kid is plus 20